# How to make an oscillator using 3 legged ceramic resonator and transistor?

Tags: oscillator, resonator

I need an oscillator which can provide 4 MHz (which does not need to be very precise) so I have bought a 3 legged 4 MHz ceramic resonator which looks like this.

[image]

I tried wiring up this ceramic like this on a breadboard...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDCGy4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But this does not seem to work!

I tried to find many online tutorials about this kind of resonator and their uses but none of the tutorials satisfied my needs.

So where does it seem to be a problem?

Please provide a circuit diagram if mine has some defects.

Comment: The breadboard itself is likely ruining your circuit. This kind of circuit is highly sensitive to parasitic capacitances, and breadboards have parasitic capacitance in spades.

Comment: @Hearth so is my circuit schematic correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Sorry, I'm far too tired to really analyze it right now.

Comment: Some infos usefull. https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/quartz-crystal-xtal/ceramic-if-rf-bandpass-filter.php   . I think ceramic filters are used with single logic CMOS inverter (see how clock is generated in microprocessor). Generally need 2 capacitors. One on input, one on output. https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262A.pdf   fig 3.4 .Will try later. Keep on.

Comment: Largest problem is that the that circuit is not an oscillator so it won't work. There is no feedback from transistor output to input, and the ceramic resonator is not on a path to have any effect on feedback. Why do the tutorials don't satisy your needs? More importantly, what are your needs? Why you must use a transistor?

Comment: For a transistor circuit that probably will work, maybe something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdynT6UTHfQ). Have fun with the wiring. Looks like some of my own. ;)

Comment: And if you don't believe me, I just started wiring [this up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLwHD.png) earlier today. I'll get back to it, tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Everyone, i need 4mhz oscillator for ShortWave radio Transmitter project , also please include a working circuit for it if mine one is wrong

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link for the resonator. Asking for circuits (on-demand) is basically asking for opinions because there are many ways to "skin a cat". Questions seeking opinions are off-topic.

Comment: Your circuit has many flaws. You might start with something very simple that has at least some potential for oscillations: https://www.edaboard.com/threads/ceramic-resonator-oscillator-circuit.178073/

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks! This one was Helpful !